# Using key property as unique Identifier

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I´m using React, Redux & Material-UI for development. I´m displaying a table which is generated from data fetched from the server via Ajax.

In general everything is working, except that I don´t know how to identify a User after selecting one - n from the generated table.

In the following I will just show small lines of code, because the overall Code is not required to provide me help (correct me if I´m wrong)

```
{allUser != null ? allUser.map((row, index) => (
                        <TableRow className="testx" key={row.userID} selected={row.selected}>
                            <TableRowColumn>
                                {/*
                                 <UserCard
                                 userData={row}
                                 displayPersonalInfo={true}
                                 showRequestDates={false}
                                 showChangePassword={false}
                                 />

                                */}
                                {row.userID}
                            </TableRowColumn>
                        </TableRow>
                    ))
                        : <TableRow><TableRowColumn>{"Keine Einträge vorhanden"}</TableRowColumn></TableRow>
                    }
```

So what I´m doing here is pretty simple. I´m just generated a table that contain UserCard´s. I have enabled `multiSelectable: true,` as default state.

I have included a `onRowSelection={this.rowSelection.bind(this)}`

```
rowSelection(key){
    console.log("select")
    console.log(key)
}
```

After the selecting a row, the `key` has a value so this is also working. **BUT**

as key I have used the userID `key={row.userID}`, but it doesn´t seem to have any affect here. If the key property is the wrong way to identify a selected User, what would be the correct way to do so?

Why is my userID not used as key? How can I identify the User selected User in the Table?

Hope anyone can help me here!

EDIT:

Here is my `render()` Code, which seems to be required to get a correct answer.

```
return (
        <div id="requestSummaryTable">
            <Table
                height={this.state.height}
                fixedHeader={this.state.fixedHeader}
                fixedFooter={this.state.fixedFooter}
                selectable={this.state.selectable}
                multiSelectable={this.state.multiSelectable}
                onRowSelection={this.rowSelection.bind(this)}
            >
                <TableHeader
                    displaySelectAll={this.state.showCheckboxes}
                    adjustForCheckbox={this.state.showCheckboxes}
                    enableSelectAll={this.state.enableSelectAll}
                >
                    {/*
                     <TableRow>
                     <TableHeaderColumn colSpan="3" tooltip="Urlaubsanträge" style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>
                     Übersicht Urlaubsanträge
                     </TableHeaderColumn>
                     </TableRow>
                     */}

                    <TableRow>
                        <TableHeaderColumn tooltip="Name">Nutzer</TableHeaderColumn>
                    </TableRow>
                </TableHeader>
                <TableBody
                    displayRowCheckbox={this.state.showCheckboxes}
                    deselectOnClickaway={this.state.deselectOnClickaway}
                    showRowHover={this.state.showRowHover}
                    stripedRows={this.state.stripedRows}
                >

                    {allUser != null ? allUser.map((row, index) => (
                        <TableRow className="testx" key={row.userID} value={row.userID} selected={row.selected}>
                            <TableRowColumn>
                                {/*
                                 <UserCard
                                 userData={row}
                                 displayPersonalInfo={true}
                                 showRequestDates={false}
                                 showChangePassword={false}
                                 />

                                */}
                                {row.userID}
                            </TableRowColumn>
                        </TableRow>
                    ))
                        : <TableRow><TableRowColumn>{"Keine Einträge vorhanden"}</TableRowColumn></TableRow>
                    }
                </TableBody>
            </Table>
        </div>
    );
```

can I somehow bind the select event to the row, to provide the userID as parameter or how is this working? It seems to be more complicated than it should be, or?

EDIT2:

Or is the only way to do this, to access the data which are generating the table rows and compare the array indexes with the row index?

Answer (score 0):

From the code that you have provide I can see that you have

`onRowSelection={this.rowSelection.bind(this)}`

but your `rowSelection` signature expects `key` as the first parameter, and you are not passing it, so `key` inside the function is `undefined`.

You have to change it to

`onRowSelection={this.rowSelection.bind(this, row.userID)}`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I can´t do it like you said, because the `userID`  can´t be accessed as you can see in my edited Q

Comment: @BayLife I see. Did you tried to use the `index` of map as the `key`?

Comment: @BayLife maybe the `rowNumber` is what is used to identify the row.

Comment: how would I access the `rowNumber` in `onRowSelection` ?